# How to change fontspec’s default options

Tags: fontspec, optional-arguments

How can I change the default font features for the `fontspec` package? For example, I have a lot of definitions like:

```
\setromanfont{FontName}[
    Path = ../fonts/,
    Extension = .otf,
    ItalicFont = *-It,
    BoldFont = *-Bd,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BdIt,
    Numbers = OldStyle
]
```

Can I factor out those attributes to make the individual definitions shorter and more flexible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set font features that will be shared with all fonts you define (unless overridden) with **`\defaultfontfeatures[<font name>]{<font features}]`** (documented in part III §1, p. 20 in [the `fontspec` manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)).

The manual’s example is:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{texgyreadventor-regular.otf}% will use standard TeX ligatures
```

But you could also set defaults like:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{
    Path = ../fonts/,
    Extension = .otf,
    Numbers = OldStyle,
}
```

Which would cut down the size of your font definitions to:

```
\setromanfont{FontName}[
    ItalicFont = *-It,
    BoldFont = *-Bd,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BdIt,
]
```

Comment: And now accept your own answer, please. Otherwise the question will remain in the unanswered list.